# How to edit OpenCart themes offline?

Tags: editor, e-commerce, opencart

I'm new to OpenCart. Unlike normal websites where you can edit the index.html offline and view your changes on a browser, OpenCart has no index.html. Since they work by combining "parts" of html using php, how do I edit my themes offline instead of editing them over my ftp?

My browser does not open OpenCart's index.php file too.

Comment: OpenCart is built up of numerous files. They also require php variables for a number of portions of the locations so it's not possible to do this with one html file

Answer (score 2):

Opencart uses PHP to generate HTML files. To 'view opencart in your browser offline' you need to run a localhost. This means running apache with PHP and a mysql database on your computer so that the PHP will 'run' and generate your output HTML files that you can view in your browser.

If you're on a windows computer look up XAMPP or if you're on a MAC look up MAMP.
[Windows Instructions](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=xampp&aq=0&oq=XAMP&aqs=chrome.0.0j57j5j0j61j60.2109&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&q=Install+opencart+locally+xampp&spell=1&sa=X&ei=nvRIUemaBIaQiAeE2YDwBg&ved=0CCwQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44011176,d.aGc&fp=400aa7d3b98d6b02&biw=1329&bih=798)
[Mac Instructions](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=xampp&aq=0&oq=XAMP&aqs=chrome.0.0j57j5j0j61j60.2109&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Install+opencart+locally+mamp&oq=Install+opencart+locally+mamp&gs_l=serp.3...52832.53103.2.53381.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.ocFkwNpYkhI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44011176,d.aGc&fp=400aa7d3b98d6b02&biw=1329&bih=798)

This is how developers create and edit templates for a range of PHP based CMS and eCommerce systems offline.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart does not have an index.html instead it has index.php, so first of all you need to install PHP xampp or apache server and mysql to run opencart on your localhost. Opencart uses templates And if you want to edit pages and see the changes you can edit the templates. Or if you want to change the default page after opening the site, you can create a page and a controller for it and change in the index.php in the end of the file there is a

```
$action = new Action('common/home');
```

you can give your page here.